# Imagemagick rotation result is blurry

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

After I rotate an image with Imagick in PHP, the result seems blurry and has lost a lot of its detail.

You can view the example here (original and rotated):

[image]

I am loading and outputting an image to the browser to the browser. 
The only difference between those 2 images seen in the url is the following line :

```
$src->rotateImage(new ImagickPixel('transparent'),6.5);
```

I have set the jpg compression to 100, but alas, it doesn't help.

```
$src->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$src->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
```

I also tried COMPRESSION_LOSSLESSJPEG.

Is it impossible to get a good result, or am I missing something? Thans for any help.

Comment: I'm afraid this much blurring is to be expected when rotating an image (except a few cases, like when rotating by 180 degrees).

Comment: I agree with @Maerlyn: Transforming a rasterized image will usually result in image losses

Comment: do you need to rotate the image or would [css3 rotation](http://www.css3maker.com/css3-transform.html) work

Comment: you can see why this'll never look "nice" with a real world example. take two pieces of mosquito netting, and put one on top of the other at a slight angle. notice the moire patterns? that's the inevitable side effect of taking a grid and putting it on an angle, then converting what's left back to a grid.

Comment: ok, thank you for your input! Well, I guess I'm just spoiled with the results software like gimp or photoshop. I guess they just have better rendering algorithms. 
@Orangepill , unfortunately, css3 rotation will not be sufficient, because I eventually want to compose an image made of different (sometimes rotated) images that the user can download.

Comment: @destiny, no I think the point being made earlier is that this is a problem with _all_ bitmap rotation, even with Gimp and Photoshop. If you get better results there generally, perhaps you are just using higher resolution images?